# How does Carrierwave store references to multiple versions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

How does [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) store different image versions without me having to create extra rows in my database? For example, Carrierwave allows me to have multiple versions of one image (i.e. small_img, medium_img, large_img, etc). How does it do this without storing a reference to it in my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses just plain old Ruby :)

Looking at [their source code](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/0cac02f17398c6f89ffe46489f294b89ac902512/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb):

1. [Here is what version does](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/0cac02f17398c6f89ffe46489f294b89ac902512/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb#L53): `build_version` is called to store the new version in an internal data structure.
2. When `store_versions` is called [later](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/0cac02f17398c6f89ffe46489f294b89ac902512/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb#L282), a copy of the image is saved for each version.
3. When using `uploader.url(:thumb)`, it iterates over the stored versions to look for the desired image ([source here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/0cac02f17398c6f89ffe46489f294b89ac902512/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb#L199))